# I am comparing array store in coredata with my own array .getting crash on fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

```
var amentitiesPredicate: NSPredicate?
        var predicates = [AnyHashable]()
        for amentity in ["1","2","3"] {
            predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "'\(amentity)' IN amenities"))  // amenities is the array store in coredata 
        }
        if predicates.count > 0 {
            if let predicates = predicates as? [NSPredicate] {
                amentitiesPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
            }
        }
```

// Creating predicate here

//--> Working fine with below predicates

```
 let distancePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "distance <= \(self.filterApplied.distanceRange)")
            let minimumPricePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "price >= \(filterApplied.leftRangePrice)")
            let maximumPricePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "price <= \(filterApplied.rightRangePrice)")
```

-->//

```
 let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [minimumPricePredicate, maximumPricePredicate, distancePredicate,amentitiesPredicate])

            self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = andPredicate
```

// fetching data from core data

```
  do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch() // getting crash here

    } catch {
        printDebug(error.localizedDescription)
        print("Fetch failed")
    }
```

Comment: That's not how you submit a search to NSFetchRequest in order to return a result.

Comment: I have posted only few lines of code @ElTomato . shall I Post more ?

Comment: What type is the amenities attribute?

Comment: @pbasdf It is type of transformable in Core data. I am storing an array of String

Comment: Even if you get the predicate format correct, it won’t work with a transformable attribute (at least, not while fetching).  Depending on your use case, you might need to have a to-many relationship in place of the array, or to use a concatenated string.  Also avoid using \() in predicates: better to use %@ and %K as CD can then infer the type and generate the correct syntax.